# Blackberry web application wrapping floating divs on top of each other

Tags: xhtml, blackberry

Our site http://m.sa2010.gov.za has a simple menu structure that relies on floating divs to stack 2 columns of menu elements. Unfortunately it seems to wrap all elements on top of each other when viewed from most Blackberry phones? Any suggestions.

works beautifully on most mobile devices including iPhone. Check it out.

Comment: seems to be very device specific... some blackberries do work correctly..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BlackBerry browser is notoriously bad for the lack of full CSS support, especially on older models.  You may have to experiment with other ways to get what you want, such as using a table-based layout.

Comment: Blackberry sucks in other words. A friend updated his firmware and now his does the same?

Comment: They supposedly have a modern webkit-based browser in their 6.0 OS (coming soon I hope) but in the meantime you can download plenty of device simulators from their site to see how your website renders on various devices and OS versions.